# Data Extraction while Image Processing in R

Tags: r, string

I am trying to read the data but as such regular expression is not helping out. Sample data is below:

```
Country Cross Transaction (ID: 12345)
Country Capital (Id: 23445)
Cross Country Trade Relation (Id:47639)
```

All the above values are in different documents, so while documents parsing I need to capture "Country Cross Transaction","Country Capital","Cross Country Trade Relation",

I can't specify how many words  I need, but I need everything before **(ID: xxxxx)** term

Answer (score 0):

You can use str_remove for this. Given that the string you want to remove starts with `(`.

```
library(stringr)
string <- "Country Cross Transaction (ID: 12345)"
string %>% str_remove(pattern = "\\(.*")
```

**EDIT**

Say your document has the following content and is saved in `test.txt`, you could do something like this:

test.txt

```
Country Cross Transaction (ID: 12345)
This should not be fetched
Country Capital (ID: 23445)
Cross Country Trade Relation (ID:47639)
```

Code

```
library(plyr)
output <- list()
document <- readLines("test.txt") %>% as.list()
for (line in seq_along(document)){
  if (str_detect(document[[line]], "\\(ID:")){
    output[[line]] <- str_remove(document[[line]], pattern = "\\(.*")
  }
}

output %>% compact
```

Comment: But the concern is to detect the string in the documents, and the only way is: I need to take all the info before (Id:xxxxx)... That is main concern

Comment: I don't get it. What is your expected output for the string that I used as an example?

Comment: I need to detect (Id:xxx), and from the line, I need to capture all the previous info from that line in the document

Comment: My expected Output should be, country cross transaction, country capital,  Cross Country Trade Relation

Comment: So, some of your lines don't have (id:xxx) and you don't want to capture those lines, but if there is an (id:xxx), you want to extract everything before (id:xxx)?

Comment: So basically in the first  document, Country Cross Transaction (ID: 12345) is present. I need to capture only Country Cross Transaction from it.  In the second document Country Capital (Id: 23445) is present, I need to capture Country Capital from it.

Comment: So, I need to find (Id =xxx) first, and then need to capture the remaining value(or the information on the left of (Id=xxx)  from that line only...